# "The server returned a non-specific error" when Grouping in a DataView

Tags: 2010, error, data-view-web-part

I am getting a "The server returned a non-specific error" with a DataView in SPD with SP2010.
The DataView is working fine up to that, i.e. I have added and removed cols, Filtered and Sorted and added Inline editing and all this works corectly in the browser after I save changes.
When I then go back into "Sort & Group" and select the Show Group Header option and select OK, The data table collapses down and gives that error ??
The Data Source is a View in SQL server.
Any suggestions gratefully received.
JK

Comment: How many items are in the view in SQL?

Comment: Also check the field type - is it having trouble grouping on this type? Start real time logging with the ULS Viewer on the server (http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer). Then go into SPD and apply your grouping. Go back to the logs after this and there's a chance you'll at least get a stack trace that'll help you get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it easy to recover the page by creating a new form in SPD, then taking the `<DataSources>` section from the new page and replacing the `<DataSources>` in the corrupted page.  Of course, if you've created special filtering, this would have to be redone.  But this is a quick way to recover the page.